# Detect duplicate values in an unsorted column in LibreOffice calc? (Q&A)

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a table, where one column is intended to represent unique IDs. Is it possible, to check with a formula, if the uniqueness criterion is fulfilled?

For instance, let's say the table is currently saying

```
ID        Summary
T1204     Fix user crash.
T1201     Fix tester crash.
T1202     Implement that feature.
T1203     Implement that other feature.
```

Let's say I now create a new entry

```
T1204     Make program say "Hello World." on startup
```

I want a formula that becomes `TRUE`, if such a duplicate occurs, or a formula that counts the number of such duplicates.

**Constraint:** Assume, that the columns need to remain ordered independently of the ID column -- e.g. by the category specified in an additional column.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant trick is to use *Array Formulas*.

In the given example:

```
    |  A      |  B                                |  C(Values) |  C(Formulae)
----|---------|-----------------------------------|------------|---------------------------
 1  |  ID     |  Summary                          |            |
 2  |  T1204  |  Fix user crash.                  |  2         |  {=COUNTIF(A2:A11;A2:A11)}
 3  |  T1201  |  Fix tester crash.                |  1         |
 4  |  T1202  |  Implement that feature.          |  1         |
 5  |  T1203  |  Implement that other feature.    |  3         |
 6  |         |                                   |  0         |
 7  |  T1204  |  Make program say "Hello World."  |  2         |
 8  |  T1203  |  Another duplicate                |  3         |
 9  |  T1203  |                                   |  3         |
10  |         |                                   |  0         |
11  |         |                                   |  0         |
```

Duplicates can then be recognized by column entries larger than one.

### How to enter an array formula

The notation `{=...}` is used by Libreoffice to denote an Array formula, but *cannot be used to enter* it. Instead, the formula has to be entered normally as `=COUNTIF(A2:A11;A2:A11)` but then be declared an array formula, by either:

- Typing a formula containing ranges, and pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd>, or
- In the formula dialog (<kbd>Ctrl+F2</kbd>) tick the "Array" checkbox.

### O(N²) time dependency

The solution does however have quadrativ time dependency; Try to enter a formula far the entire column, such as `{=COUNTIF(A:A;A:A)}`, and you have a good change of crashing LibreOffice.

What it does should effectively amount to:

```
for i from 2 to 11
    set cell C,i to sum over:
        for j from 2 to 11:
            1 if cell A,i matches cell A,j
            0 otherwise
```

In practice, I've found it hard to reproduce, what array formulas REALLY do, and changing them usually involves some trial-and-error.

### Alternative: Detect IF there are duplicates.

Alternatively, the array formula `{=SUM(COUNTIF(A2:A11;A2:A11)) - COUNTA(A2:A11)}` can be used, which will be positive *if* there are duplicates and zero otherwise. The advantage of this approach is that the array formula can interfere with editing features, such as Drag&Drop of whole table rows.

Answer (score 1):

Much more simply just sort the ID column and then in another column enter a formula that checks if the previous value is equal =if(A2=A1;TRUE;FALSE)

Comment: That assumes, that sorting is possible though. In the use-case that motivated my write-up, the IDs had to be vertically sorted by status. Good point for clarification though.